# IDEA , run java there is one line code still on the top like the picture

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[image]

just like this. Didn't I correctly configure the environment variables?

Comment: no code, no error message, no context ... what do you want us to get from that?

Comment: There is no error shown here - It's unclear what you are asking about

Answer (score 0):

The "one line" on the top is the JVM starting (on a mac); that is not an error. Your program output looks like it follows as

```
this is a test
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But could  I cancel display this? Well , I am a little obsessive-compulsive....

Comment: @LqS2 as far as I know you can't, but this will only output when running it with intellj. When you run a .jar file the console won't have such a message